# Progress bar disappears with cart, but footer icon list also vanishes in WooCommerce site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes, devtools

[image]I've implemented a progress bar for the shopping cart page on my WooCommerce site in the theme.php file, and it works as expected by disappearing when the cart is empty. However, I've encountered an issue where not only does the progress bar vanish, but the icon list in the footer also disappears when the cart is empty.

```
function remove_elementor_widget_container_if_cart_empty() {
    // Check if WooCommerce is active and if we are on the cart page
    if ( class_exists('WooCommerce') && is_cart() && WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        // If the cart is empty and it's the cart page, remove the elementor-widget-container div
        add_filter('the_content', 'remove_elementor_widget_container');
    }
}

function remove_elementor_widget_container($content) {
    // Remove the elementor-widget-container div from the content using regular expression
    $content = preg_replace('/<div class="elementor-widget-container">.*?<\/div>/s', '', $content);
    return $content;
}

add_action('wp', 'remove_elementor_widget_container_if_cart_empty');[![Progress bar][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I added a CSS ID to the progress bar's container and modified the code to set the container's display to "none."

```
function custom_hide_widget_if_cart_empty($content) {
    // Check if WooCommerce is active and if we are on the cart page
    if ( class_exists('WooCommerce') && is_cart() && WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        // Add a script to hide the widget container by setting its display to "none"
        $content .= '<script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                var widgetToHide = document.getElementById("wagen-icons");
                if (widgetToHide) {
                    widgetToHide.style.display = "none";
                }
            });
        </script>';
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'custom_hide_widget_if_cart_empty');
```